# Extract software from a list of titles using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a list of vulnerability titles, and need to extract specific software names from those titles. I would like to write a method to which I pass a title, and a regex, which then returns a list of matching software in that title. For example, I may pass in the title:

```
Mozilla Thunderbird Remote Code Execution / SeaMonkey RANDOM Firefox MORE TEXT Thunderbird
```

and a regular expression such as:

```
^Mozilla.*(Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey)
```

and I would like the method to return;

```
['Thunderbird', 'SeaMonkey', 'Firefox', 'Thunderbird'].
```

As another example, I may pass in

```
Amazing Microsoft Office Word and Excel RCE
```

and my regex may look like;

```
.*Microsoft.*(Word|Excel)+
```

and I would like the method to return;

```
['Word', 'Excel']
```

The titles are not always uniform.

---

I've been having trouble getting regex and group/capture code working to capture the full list of software. Here is what I have so far in C# (the title and regex are currently hard coded for troubleshooting)

```
        string title = "Mozilla Thunderbird Remote Code Execution / SeaMonkey RANDOM Firefox MORE TEXT Thunderbird";
        string pattern = @"^Mozilla.*(Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey)";

        Match match = Regex.Match(title, pattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", match.Value);
            for (int ctr = 1; ctr < match.Groups.Count; ctr++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}:  {1}", ctr, match.Groups[ctr].Value);
                int captureCtr = 0;
                foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[ctr].Captures)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}",
                                      captureCtr, capture.Value);
                    captureCtr++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Which outputs;

```
Matched text: Mozilla Thunderbird RANDOM TEXT SeaMonkey MORE RANDOM TEXT Firefox  MORE TEXT Thunderbird
Group 1:  Thunderbird    
Capture 0: Thunderbird
```

How can I modify my code/regex to extract the full list of software for each title?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://regex101.com/r/mXXkWc/1 I have just used `(Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey)` with `img` modifiers.

Comment: [`(Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey)(?:.*?(Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey)(?:.*(Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey))?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/9xudVd/2)? Although, I'd suggest simply doing a string search against a list of words.

Comment: @ctwheels I am hoping to avoid repeating the list of software as the groups can occur many times (i..e. if the software is listed multiple times, id like to capture every instance as a group)

Comment: @n00b your best bet is honestly to match against a list and do a string search.

Comment: I feel like we need a little more context here around what you are trying to do with these groups, because, honestly (for example) `"abac".match(/(ab|ac)(ab|ac)/);` and `"abac".match(/(ab|ac)/g);` are going to give you (functionally) identical results . . .

Comment: @talemyn I am actually using c#/.net which apparently affords me some functionality that I dont have with JS regex alone. Please see my updated question/details.

Comment: You should not be doing that with a single regex, although it is possible. You just want to find several matches in a string that contains another string. So, all you need is `if (s.Contains(qualifier_word)) { return Regex.Matches(s, @"Firefox|Thunderbird|SeaMonkey").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList(); }`. Certainly, the regex for extraction is only necessary if you plan to use a whole word search, otherwise, all you need is `.Contains`

Comment: So, 1) Are you interested in whole word matching? 2) If whole word matching is required, can there be non-word chars in the search words? 3) What about a `.Contains` solution?

Comment: Hi, if you think my previous answer solved this question please remove it.