# Find all matches with an extra qualifying criteria

Tags: c#, regex

Given sentences such as;

```
Boy has a dog and a cat.
Boy microwaves a gerbil.
Sally owns a cat.
```

For each sentence I want a list of animals (defined as 'dog' 'cat' or 'gerbil') where "Boy" is the first word. For the list above that would be;

```
['dog', 'cat']
['gerbil']
3rd sentence would not match.
```

The regex;

```
dog|cat|gerbil
```

Will return all matches, but not specific to boy (the third sentence would return an undesirable 'cat').

```
^Boy.*(dog|cat|gerbil)
```

[Returns](https://regex101.com/r/mXXkWc/3) the entire phrase up to the last matching animal, such as "Boy has a dog and a cat", whereas the first and only group is "cat".

How do I get the list of all animals associated with "Boy" (that is, animals in sentences starting with "Boy")?

Comment: Would this need to account for something like `Boy does not have a gerbil but does own a cat`? That could get tricky.

Comment: No. If it starts with boy, I want all animals in that sentence. Whether that be matches or groups I dont care, I just need the animals alone, in all phrases beginning with 'Boy'.

Comment: edited question to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Just use `(?<=^Boy.*?)(?:dog|cat|gerbil)` or - to match as whole words - [`(?<=^Boy.*?)\b(?:dog|cat|gerbil)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5eBoy.*%3f%29%5cb%28%3f%3adog%7ccat%7cgerbil%29%5cb&i=Boy+has+a+dog+and+a+cat.%0d%0aBoy+something+a+gerbil.%0d%0aSally+owns+a+cat.&o=m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^Boy.*?)(?:dog|cat|gerbil)
```

Or, a variation with word boundaries to match the animals as whole words:

```
(?<=^Boy\b.*?)\b(?:dog|cat|gerbil)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5eBoy%5cb.*%3f%29%5cb%28%3f%3adog%7ccat%7cgerbil%29%5cb&i=Boy+has+a+dog+and+a+cat.%0d%0aBoy+something+a+gerbil.%0d%0aSally+owns+a+cat.&o=m)

The `(?<=^Boy.*?)` positive lookbehind will require the `Boy` at the start of the string for the consuming pattern to match.

If your input contains LF (newline) chars, pass the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option for `.` to match newlines, too.

C# usage:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=^Boy\b.*?)\b(?:dog|cat|gerbil)\b")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/H1gCWv):

```
var strs = new List<string>() { "Boy has a dog and a cat.", 
        "Boy something a gerbil.",
        "Sally owns a cat." };
foreach (var s in strs)
{
    var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=^Boy\b.*?)\b(?:dog|cat|gerbil)\b")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToList();
     if (results.Count > 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:\n[{1}]\n------", s, string.Join(", ", results));
     }
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:\nNO MATCH!\n------", s);
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Boy has a dog and a cat.:
[dog, cat]
------
Boy something a gerbil.:
[gerbil]
------
Sally owns a cat.:
NO MATCH!
------
```

**There is an alternative**: match any string starting with `Boy` and then after each successful match only:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|^Boy\b).*?\b(dog|cat|gerbil)\b
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cG%28%3f!%5cA%29%7c%5eBoy%5cb%29.*%3f%5cb%28dog%7ccat%7cgerbil%29%5cb&i=Boy+has+a+dog+and+a+cat.%0d%0aBoy+something+a+gerbil.%0d%0aSally+owns+a+cat.&o=m) (or a [regex101 link here](https://regex101.com/r/h0BLIU/1))

You would just need to grab Group 1 contents:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:\G(?!\A)|^Boy\b).*?\b(dog|cat|gerbil)\b")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/tTbBFW).

Here,

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^Boy\b)` - either the end of the precvious match (`\G(?!\A)`) or the start of the string followed with the whole word `Boy`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than a newline (if no `RegexOptions.Singleline` is passed to the `Regex` constructor) as few as possible
- `\b(dog|cat|gerbil)\b` - a whole word `dog`, `cat` or `gerbil`

Bascially, these regexps are similar, although `\G` based regex might turn out a bit faster.

Comment: Should probably ensure `^Boy\b` though just in case the first word is something like `Boycott`

Comment: @ctwheels Yeah, that should go to the second suggestion.

Comment: @n00b There is another alternative - `(?:\G(?!\A)|^Boy\b).*?\b(dog|cat|gerbil)\b` and grab `m.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: Is it possible to acomplish the same end goal but with groups instead of matches (i.e. the first sentence would return group 1 as "dog" and group 2 as "cat")?

Comment: @n00b No, because there are as many groups as there are `(...)`, capturing groups, in the pattern  + 1 (the whole match is in Group 0). You can access them via `Captures`, but I do not think that is sane. What are your additional requirements?

Comment: What you have provided may be sufficient. I am attempting to write one method that takes in a vendor/vulnerability title, and a software regex, and I want to apply the same logic everytime to extract a list of software. I was thinking extracting 'groups' instead of 'matches' to get the list of software, but using matches maybe easier after all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142085/extract-software-from-a-list-of-titles-using-regex?noredirect=1#comment81236155_47142085 for more detail, but you have essentially given me the answer here.

Comment: @n00b I see, the questions look quite different though, and this one will help only a bit. Let's discuss that question in that thread.